# Как написать запрос к базе так, чтобы сделать выборку, сравнив данные в базе с имеющимися, приведя их к нижнему регистру

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

у меня в базе имеется запись адреса, в формате `'Улица Карла Маркса дом 9'`, когда производится добавление новой записи, мне нужно сделать проверку на наличие данной записи в базе, но чтобы это сделать корректно, хочу привести данные из базы и новую запись к нижнему регистру и сравнить. Проблема в том, что в мануале codeigniter я не нашёл, как это сделать. Как можно сделать это? Потому что у обычного `$this->db->get_where()` такой возможности, как я понял, нет. То есть вариант `$this->db->get_where('addresses, ['value' => $data['address'])->row('id');` как-то доработать что-ли. Заранее благодарю.

Comment: *чтобы это сделать корректно, хочу привести данные из базы и новую запись к нижнему регистру и сравнить.* Если при сравнении учитывается регистр - смените COLLATION поля, либо укажите его явно в условии отбора/сравнения.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не надо ничего никуда приводить. 
Все приводится само.

По умолчанию MySQL делает регистронезависимый поиск.

Перед тем как задавать вопрос, или - если брать шире - в принципе озабочиваться какой-либо проблемой, надо сначала убедиться, что она существует в реальности, а не в твоем воображении. То есть банально надо сначала сделать, а потом спрашивать.

Comment: *По умолчанию БД делает регистронезависимый поиск.* Ммм... а откуда взяты эти сведения? Поиск совершенно однозначно завязан на COLLATION... или имеется в виду то, что дефолтные настройки, задаваемые при установке, выбирают CI collation?

Comment: дефолтные настройки, задаваемые при установке, выбирают CI collation

Comment: Спасибо большое